# Setting up own environment variable lookup

Tags: java, environment-variables, environment

I have standalone Java application ,in that i have various modules 
Application starts from one classes main() method and then application goes on.

Now i wanted share variables in form of key/value pair to various modules

How can i do it ?

Update :

From main() which kicks on application , from there i will be setting some variables.
and also from here it starts some modules programs ,

I just want similar functionality like ServletContext , SessionContext variables , just like in  Servlet container

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Can you try to make your question more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for JVM wide simple string based key/value configuration storage then the system properties are usually a good fit: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Anywhere in your code you can use:

```
String configThingValue = System.getProperty("config-thing");

System.setProperty("config-thing", "config thing value");
```

Also, `System.getProperties()` provides a map like set of properties (it extends `Hashtable`).

Comment: but it will be restricted to application right??
will it add this variable to OS env or persist till application lives?

Comment: This is strictly limited to the JVM you're classes are running in.  Java properties have a well defined file format for persistance though.  If you're going to do that though, use a separate `Properties` instance from the System properties.  Check out the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html